# How well is the brain protected from physical hits ? Can small hits or blows cause brain damage?

Tags: brain, protection

Small punches like Diaz does to himself here :

https://youtu.be/F5OYXELOwjQ#t=195s

I am just curious about how hard must a punch be to cause even light brain damage or IQ loss.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the[reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the brain is well-protected from physical hits. The skull and scalp protect the brain from direct blows, and the cerebrospinal fluid (CSF) cushioning system protects it from jarring forces. However, even a hit that doesn't result in a full-blown concussion can cause injury to the brain.

The severity of a brain injury depends on many factors, including the force or impact of the blow, where on the head it lands, and how fast and hard the head is moving at the time of impact. Brain injuries can range from mild (where symptoms disappear within a few days or weeks) to severe (leading to permanent disability or death).

Here's a relevant reference for further reading: https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20200702-the-helmets-that-can-keep-your-brain-safe

Comment: Hi, welcome to Medical Sciences.SE. Although this has the makings of a good answer, this site requires answers to provide at least minimal supporting references. Even if the things you're saying are well established medicine, they provide the audience with additional sources to learn more.

Comment: Welcome! It's nice to see a good answer. I need to second @CareyGregory's comment; answer need to be supported with reliable sources, a custom on this site since its inception. It has been a source of annoyance/frustration to many users, but is required because many people don't know the proper response but post (erroneous) answers anyway. If you were a seasoned user, as unkind as it seems, I would probably downvote you for lack of a reference. FWIW, even MDs and PhDs on this site cite references for every answer. Some users do not, but may get a "post notice" asking for one. Sorry.